# Is there an easy way to have no choices selected in filter?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel 2010 when I turn on the filter and click on the down arrow "Select All", and therefore all choices, is selected.  Turning off all choices is as easy as unchecking "Select All".  However sometimes I am so focused on looking for a specific value I forget to uncheck it.  Is there an easy (non macro, non VBA) way to have none of the choices checked when you click on the down arrow?

In the example I really only want to filter to "31".  Other then scrolling back up, uncheck "Select All" then scrolling down to find "31" again is there another option.  This is particuallry a pain when you have hundreds of options in the list.

[image]

Comment: Hi Welcome to SuperUser. I tried reproducing the question but I'm not able to follow what is happening and what you are asking. Can you provide more details and steps to reproduce.

Comment: @Brad: I believe that he’s saying that, when he clicks on the down arrow in the corner of the header cell of a filtered column, he wants the initial default to be Nothing Selected instead of “(Select All)”.

Comment: I edited the question, because this has bothered me also.  The best solution would be if I could click "31" a couple times, and Excel would deselect everything but "31".

Answer (score 1):

Select **Filter Numbers** --> **equals** and then enter `31`.  You should get the filtering you're looking for.

[image]

[image]

Using this to filter things is far easier than doing what you're trying to do plus you can make them as simple or complicated as you need them to be.

Comment: The example was an over simplification. The values are usually complex words or phrases, and you don't really know what the value is until you find it.  The question really is about how to make a single selection when you have not unchecking "Select All" first.

Comment: @JamesJenkins this filter isn't just restricted to numbers.  You can do textual filtering as well.  I would suggest that if you're doing any type of complex filtering use this means instead.  I know it's not the solution you were looking for exactly, but in my opinion is the most optimal solution for this situation.

Comment: @ KronoS, I understand filtering and assume that wally cpa does also. You are missing the question.

Answer (score 0):

Q: Is there an easy (non macro, non VBA) way to have none of the choices checked when you click on the down arrow?

A: I do not beleive there is a way to set the defualt value for "(Select All)" to "unchecked".

I have also searched for a solution and not found it.